# UI bugs in Wallet on iOS 14

Tags: ios, bug, ui, wallet, cards-app

Three bugs:

1. I have added all of my cards to Apple Wallet on iOS 14, but this notice still shows really big when I open the app:

[image]

2. The cards have been lumped together with my flight tickets in the same stack. Unlike before where they were front an center.
3. Some old flight ticket is showing before all of my cards and the UI doesn’t let me reorder them and just keeps them there.

How do I fix these odd bugs? I’ve tried restarting my phone and the app.

Comment: Can you share more screenshots? Why aren’t you removing old flight tickets? I think you can hide the card in screenshot, I did it somehow initially. All works great for me, no bugs. Cards on top stack, passes on bottom.

Comment: You can blur/cover the sensitive stuff. Old airline tickets have no value, they just create clutter - why wouldn’t you delete them?

Comment: I’m addressing point 3 about an old airline ticket that you don’t want to see at the top of your list.

Comment: The airline ticket appears above the cards. They’ve been lumped together and there’s no more separation.